# Opposite of const - in other words, a writeonly qualifier?

Tags: c++

I was reading Stroustrup's c++ [FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#constplacement) and I noticed that, at one point, he had a *writeonly* qualifier in the language. After some discussion, a colleague and I could only come up with one purpose - side effects, specifically in the case of some memory mapped IO. Is there any other legitimate usage for a *writeonly* qualifier?

Comment: As an aside, we thought that for a language where everything is accomplished my mutating state, perhaps having state where the _only_ thing you can do with it is mutate it would be the highest, purest type of imperative programming :)

Comment: also, your title says "opposite" but you ask about legitimate use of writeonly, so you may want to change it

Comment: @Code Monkey Thanks, I edited the title to hopefully be more grammatically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `write-only` qualifier would be useful for hardware registers since reading from a `write-only` register would lead to undefined behavior or subtle run-time errors. You can use a `#define` such as `#define write-only` and then apply this to a register like, `special_register write_only UTXBUF;`

There is a blog post at EE Times on [How to Enforce write-only access](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4024953/How-to-enforce-write-only-access).

Comment: +1 We stumbled across that article during our discussion - certainly preventing someone from reading from write only registers at compile time would preclude a range of bugs.

Answer (score 4):

It's made a comeback in C++ AMP, GPGPU extensions to the language, where it's used to tell the run-time that they don't have to copy certain buffers from host to device.

Comment: +1 Interesting - that's a use case I had not considered... optimizing synchronization of outside buffers.

Comment: sorry, we are taking writeonly away in the Beta and replacing it with a discard_data() method... will be blogging that soon...

Answer (score 3):

It is useful for many type of hardware interfaces which do not allow reading the computer's output, or in which the input is status and the output is control, etc.

In my device driver writing days, this occurred pretty frequently among hardware designs.  1970s hardware was relatively expensive to add a buffer which could read back that which was last written to it, or there was a cost-saving interface at the same address as the output register which returned something else about the device.  When and where it mattered, the driver had to maintain a copy of the last value written to consult if, for example, an update would actually cause a change in state.